# Cantor set does not contain any interval

Tags: real-analysis

Cantor set does not contain any interval of the form $(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}, \frac{3k+2}{3^m})$ where $k$ and $m$ are positive integers. Now suppose it contains an interval of the form $(\alpha, \beta)$ then it will contain a segment of the above form if $$3^{-m} < \frac{\beta-\alpha}{6}$$. I did not understand how this expression came. Should not the value of $k$ also be specified ?

Comment: Yes, it will contain an interval of the above form for at least one value of $k$. When you add one to $k$ the left endpoint increases by $3^{1-m}$, so it will eventually belong to the first half of $(\alpha,\beta)$ and then the right endpoint will also belong to $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Answer (score 0):

For given $m$, we can split up the interval $[0..1]$ in segments of the form:

$$\left(\frac{3k}{3^m}..\frac{3k+3}{3^m}\right)$$

simply by letting $k$ run from $0$ to $3^{m-1}-1$ (dealing with the points $\frac{3k}{3^m}$ is a detail I will not go into -- it's not hard). Each of these intervals contains a unique interval of the form:

$$\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}..\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$$

The condition that is specified ensures that $(\alpha..\beta)$ is more than $2\cdot 3^{1-m}$ wide. Therefore, $\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2$ is more than $3^{1-m}$ away from $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Now, (a number arbitrarily close to) $\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2$ needs to be in one of the large intervals $(\frac{3k}{3^m}..\frac{3k+3}{3^m})$.

As the length of this interval is $3^{1-m}$, it must be contained in $(\alpha..\beta)$.

> **Remark** We see that the bound is naively tight: $3^{-m} < \dfrac{\beta-\alpha}6$ is necessary to be sure that the larger interval fits. However, since $\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}..\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$ is the *middle* third of $(\frac{3k}{3^m}..\frac{3k+3}{3^m})$, we can get away with one third smaller, i.e. $3^{-m} < \dfrac{\beta-\alpha}9$, at the cost of more complicated reasoning.

Transitivity of subsets now establishes that:

$$\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}..\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right) \subseteq (\alpha ..\beta)$$

for some suitable $k$.

In principle, we could express $k$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but this is fiddly, and not important for the conclusion that is to be attained.

Comment: I don't think that this condition is necessary although here the sufficiency is enough. Also these statements are not clear : "The condition that is specified ensures that $(\alpha..\beta)$ is more than $2\cdot 3^{1-m}$ wide; in particular, then, there must exist a large interval $(\frac{3k}{3^m}..\frac{3k+3}{3^m})$ inside $(\alpha..\beta)$, since $\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2$ is covered by these intervals."

Comment: @prasenjit Expanded that part and commented on necessity.

Comment: Can't we find any condition just from the inequalities : $\frac{3k+1}{3^m} > \alpha$ and $\frac{3k+1}{3^m} < \beta$

Comment: @prasenjit That's possible of course, but it's easy to make mistakes: if we manipulate, we easily lose the $k$, which in turn means the condition we obtain is implied by, but *does not imply*, the two conditions you mention.